# Restkit "cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod" on Already Running Request/Mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, restkit

I'm using Restkit (0.20.3), compiling onto iPhone 5s (8.4) simulator.

So I've seen many posts regarding the "cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod" in order to cancel a request. I currently have a request with a large JSON package that takes several seconds to map into CoreData. The user can choose to manually cancel the request via a button.

If my understanding is correct, this "cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod" should stop the request even if it's currently running? If not, then my question is how to go about doing that. But if that's supposed to stop the current operation, then it doesn't seem to be working, based on the logs because I still see a lot of print statements for mapping for the API in question.

Here's my code for starting the API:

```
@try{
        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:path
                                               parameters:nil
                                                  success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {}                                                     failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {}
@catch(NSException *e) {
    NSLog(@"%@", e);
}
```

Here's my code for cancelling, when the user presses the button:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueuedObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod:RKRequestMethodAny matchingPathPattern:path]);
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod:RKRequestMethodAny matchingPathPattern:path];
NSLog(@"%@", [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueuedObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod:RKRequestMethodAny matchingPathPattern:path]);
```

The first NSLog shows `state: Executing, isCancelled=NO`

The second NSLog shows `state: Executing, isCancelled=YES`

So I've succeeded in **cancelling** it, but the mapping still continues to show up in my logs. Is it possible to stop its **execution** as well at that point in time?

Answer (score 0):

It will stop, but not immediately. Logs also take time to print and are coming from multiple different threads so you can't 100% rely on the order of some items.

When you cancel an operation you're just setting a flag, it's up to the operation to check that flag and stop. Each operation chooses a different time (or set of times) to check based on what they do and how they do it. So, whatever the operation is doing internally when you cancel it will complete and then it'll stop a little while later.

One of the key things is that future cancelled operations won't even start and current cancelled operations won't call the completion handler.